# Every time I restart my computer, an app I use (Synergy) disappears. Running Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, synergy

If i log in and out or if I restart my computer, Synergy always disappears. I was using the PC a few days ago, got synergy installed and running, and then I rebooted. Synergy didn't start up and I could find it in Applications or recent or even by searching the dash.

When I tried to install it using Ubuntu software center, it shows already installed. So I removed it, reinstalled it and it started working again. At this point I also set it to load on Startup through Synergy settings and also by clicking the gear in the top right and Startup Applications...

I rebooted again and it's gone again. It's also missing from Startup applications and also from the dash search. I still see in /usr/bin/ synergyc, synergyd, and synergys but none of them run if I double click them (or right-click-> Open).

Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: Does `ps -ef|grep synergy` show any output? Also: in the comments of synergy someone says: "But a word of warning: You may find it crashing at weird times, such as when you press the shift key, as in this bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/synergy/+bug/992451

If that happens to you, go to the synergy webpage and download version 1.4.9+. The version in the repository here is out of date--1.3.8--and updating should fix your issue." Might be worth a try.

Comment: Hi I really had to use the PC and didn't have time to troubleshoot (right after opening this thread), so I plugged in a mouse and keyboard and reinstalled synergy. I did a reboot a few days after that (for updates) and it did startup normally. Thanks for your reply. If the issue comes up again I'll update this post.

Answer (score 1):

It's a case of getting synergy to autostart after reboots. You're not the first to battle with synergy autostart; googling should bring up many results, and it's been answered [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15212/start-synergy-on-boot?rq=1) too. I've even blogged about it in the past for [gdm3 under Debian](http://nixnote.blogspot.co.uk/search/label/Synergy). So, you're definitely not alone in your troubles!

In summary, getting it to start after you've logged on is just a case of adding the command (synergys/synergyc depending) with appropriate args to Session & Startup's autostart list. There's a little more work to get it autostarting at the point of login, since that's a separate invocation in a separate context, but typically it's just a case of adding the command to the appropriate display manager init file.

I used to have it autostarting on previous distros, but nowadays I just invoke it manually after logging in, since I reboot infrequently (and the repo version is relatively unstable, so I typically have to restart it periodically anyway).

A quick `synergyc 192.168.x.x` does the trick (for the client, obviously).