# How to add startup services?

Tags: startup, services, upstart, startup-applications, startupmanager

I'm on 12.10 and I use [Synergy](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/synergy) to share my mouse between my laptop and desktop monitors. I tend to start the `synergys` daemon manually, but I'd like for it to start automatically after boot. Now I've found [the answer for synergy in particular](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15212/start-synergy-on-boot), but I'm left wondering what the standard way of adding startup services is.

What's the way to add such startup services nowadays? Is there a graphical tool to add and manage them?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/15212/start-synergy-on-boot (see the 2nd comment)

Comment: Thanks a lot, that solved my issue with synergy, but I'd still like to get an answer for the general case. I've rephrased the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might find some information you're looking for here:

[www.ubuntugeek.com/boot-up-manager-bum-graphical-runlevel-editor.html](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/boot-up-manager-bum-graphical-runlevel-editor.html)

And here:

[www.marzocca.net/linux/bum.html](http://www.marzocca.net/linux/bum.html)

In brief, **Boot-Up Manager** might serve the purpose well, and it can be installed in this way:

```
apt-get install bum
```

[image]