# How to autostart synergy on ubunutu 14.04?

Tags: gdm, autostart

I am using synergy to share mouse and keyboard.
I would like it to start automatically and have used the tutorial for this [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynergyHowto).

I am new to ubuntu and cannot find this menu:

*System Menu > Preferences > Startup Applications*

So I tried the *before logging in* steps:

But I cannot find the file `/etc/gdm/Init/Default`

I have been able to find `/usr/share/gdm/autostart/LoginWindow/` but there isn't anything of use there.

In `/etc` there is only `/etc/gdb`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are making your life too difficult.

All I had to do:

- dash search for "startup applications".

[image: Startup Application Preferences]

[image: Edit Startup Program]

To auto start the client place this in the command box:

```
synergyc [<host name or ip address>]
```

For server:

```
synergys
```

However this will not autostart synergy prior to login.

---

Regarding auto-start see: https://askubuntu.com/a/196853/15811

---

> system Menu > Preferences > Startup Applications

This is Ubuntu prior to Unity so VERY old.

Comment: Unforunately I cannot accept this answer as synergy shows up but you still hae to click the `start` button meaning I need another mouse connected to the pc just for this purpose

Comment: Not when I do it. It shows in the panel and is usuable straight after boot. And I do not believe I made any changes to settings related to auto-starting (though I did mess around with settings a lot to get it to work :P )

Comment: I found this on auto-starting: http://askubuntu.com/a/196853/15811