# run script on startup

Tags: command-line, scripts, startup, 15.10, synergy

Currently I am looking for a solution to run a script upon start up, not login, start up.

I have been researching this specifically for Synergy, but with the new version of Ubuntu (15.10) the documentation I have been following is different as folders and files do not exist where they specify. So for simple clarification, can someone please explain where I can add my Synergy start up script so that when the PC boots it runs the script before login?

I have referenced the many Synergy "how to's" on the Ubuntu forums and same thing, the files and folders they explain do not exist.

this was one of the main sources for me to follow and still was unable to get it running before login.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynergyHowto

EDIT/UPDATE:

I have tried to modify the rc.local file and adding the line:

/usr/bin/synergyc -n MACHINE_NAME Server_IP

this unfortunately does not work, there was an error after logging into the machine stating that synergy crashed. Is there something wrong with my command? it works when entering it into terminal so i believe this command is fine.

Comment: Here you go: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47695/how-to-write-startup-script-for-systemd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On ubuntu 15.10 using Cron did not work. I had to modify the file:
`/usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-ubuntu.conf`

and adding the line
`greeter-setup-script=/usr/bin/synergyc <ip/host>'`

i was able to have Synergy start up and run BEFORE logging into the system. This was vrey important to me.

Thanks for the help Eddie!

EDIT: this was a default ubuntu 15.10 setup only updates were done to the system.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at:

/usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-ubuntu.conf
You need add this line at the end of the file:

greeter-setup-script=/usr/bin/synergyc IP/HOSTNAME
(Where  is the name/IP of the server you are connecting to.)

Comment: This unfortunately does not work. Unless I might try building a script file, and call the script from the rc.local rather then putting my terminal commands straight into the rc.local file.

Comment: either should work, really. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to have synergy start up at boot up so I can log in using a keyboard and mouse not attached to the Ubuntu system.

Comment: OK try this: edit /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf and add a line at the end "greeter-setup-script=/usr/bin/synergyc <ip/host>"... then restart lightdm. From here:http://askubuntu.com/questions/15212/start-synergy-on-boot/196853#196853

Comment: Hi Eddie, no files reside under the /etc/lightdm folder only a users.conf file. There is no lightdm.conf.

Comment: @SeanMcCoy Do you have this file? /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-ubuntu.conf

Comment: I updated the answer. I hope it helps.

Comment: Yes I do, shal I modify it like the above post you suggested? 'greeter-setup-script=/usr/bin/synergyc <ip/host>'

Comment: The above worked, Can you make a post below rather then a reply then I can mark your answer as correct and close this post. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: OK I simplified it to just your case. SHould help anyone who comes back by on 15.10 :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding a cron task to run at STARTUP.

```
crontab -e
```

lets you edit the cron, and then if you add this to it, it'll run at any start of your system.  Yes, the @reboot is quite deceiving.

```
@reboot /path/to/script
```

If you have questions you can visit it [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/814/how-to-run-scripts-on-start-up), or shoot me another comment.
Cron is only meant to run in a single profile, though.

```
 man crontab
```

This command should give you more documentation on cron.

*The -l option causes the current crontab to be displayed on standard output.
The -r option causes the current crontab to be removed.
The -e option is used to edit the current crontab using the editor specified by the EDITOR environment variable.*

Comment: 15.10 has swiched to systemd, and doesn't use upstart anymore.

Comment: @mikewhatever  Fixing that.

Comment: So will the reply Anxionos gave work? or is this now no longer in use.