# Have the display manager start synergy server before login in ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: login, services, automation, synergy

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and Windows 10 PC with Synergy Version: 1.11.1rc2-4a90760e. On Windows client, it is automatically started before login and works fine. My ubuntu server doesn't have autostart feature and I would like to add it in order to be able to login on Windows even before Ubuntu login.

I have tried multiple solutions with no avail. Lastly, I have settled on creating a service file that calls the application starup scrip.
Check the service status:

```
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/synergy@justech.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2021-02-11 08:09:05 EAT; 36min ago
 Main PID: 1021 (synergysauto)
    Tasks: 4 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/system-synergy.slice/synergy@justech.service
           ├─1021 /bin/bash /usr/local/bin/synergysauto
           └─1064 synergys -f -d INFO --name Hp -c /etc/synergy.conf -a 10.42.0.1:45000 --log /var/log/synergy.log

Feb 11 08:41:47 Delta synergysauto[1021]: [2021-02-11T08:41:47] INFO: switch from "Lenovo" to "Hp" at 1361,196
Feb 11 08:41:47 Delta synergysauto[1021]: [2021-02-11T08:41:47] INFO: entering screen
Feb 11 08:41:48 Delta synergysauto[1021]: [2021-02-11T08:41:48] INFO: switch from "Hp" to "Lenovo" at 0,289
Feb 11 08:41:48 Delta synergysauto[1021]: [2021-02-11T08:41:48] INFO: leaving screen
Feb 11 08:42:08 Delta synergysauto[1021]: [2021-02-11T08:42:08] INFO: switch from "Lenovo" to "Hp" at 1355,401
Feb 11 08:42:08 Delta synergysauto[1021]: [2021-02-11T08:42:08] INFO: entering screen
Feb 11 08:42:09 Delta synergysauto[1021]: [2021-02-11T08:42:09] INFO: switch from "Hp" to "Lenovo" at 0,251
Feb 11 08:42:09 Delta synergysauto[1021]: [2021-02-11T08:42:09] INFO: leaving screen
Feb 11 08:44:57 Delta synergysauto[1021]: [2021-02-11T08:44:57] INFO: switch from "Lenovo" to "Hp" at 1364,586
Feb 11 08:44:57 Delta synergysauto[1021]: [2021-02-11T08:44:57] INFO: entering screen
~
```

Check service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Synergy Server
After=network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/synergysauto
Restart=on-failure
User=%i

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The synergys startup file is initiated as a process as seen in the service status output and looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash

# use the following defined address and configuration file.
# The option --daemon runs the process in the background
# Use Hp as the server name instead of the hostname
# Execute
synergys -f -d INFO --name Hp -c /etc/synergy.conf -a 10.42.0.1:45000 --log /var/log/synergy.log

# Exit status
exit 0
```

Now everything is working fine except that the server cannot access the primary screen when logged out.
I have confirmed this in the virtual console accessed before login to the GUI. In the synergy log file there was 'WARNING' message stating can't leave screen `Hp to Lenovo` which are my screens set in the config file.If you check closely you will see that I must be logged in as a certain user in the GUI for synergy to access the primary `X Server`. The service is start using command `sudo systemctl start synergy@$(whoami)` and enabled with `sudo systemctl enable synergy@$(whoami)`.

How can I have the display manager start the server? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question is highly related to https://askubuntu.com/questions/15212/start-synergy-on-boot?rq=1 but the link provided in the answer here does not work. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

After a detailed research I have arrived to light on this issue. Synergy uses X server and
to have run before login we need to let GNOME Display Manager start the service. To achieve this we have to create and edit:

```
edit;
/etc/gdm3/Init/Default
/etc/gdm3/PostLogin/Default

create a session file:
/etc/X11/Xsession.d/85synergys
```

The session file confirms to be working as it is responsible for staring the server when a user login session is created. However, the dgm3 does not start the server before login and after logging out. I am calling for help to improve this answer please.

References:

[SynergyHowTo](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynergyHowto#Autostart_Synergy_before_logging_in_.28GDM.29)

[Ubuntu Maunuals](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/gdm3.8.html)